# Adding attribute list to combobox in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes, combo-box

I am developing a simple plugin at the moment which contains 3 combo boxes:

- comboBox_1
- comboBox_2
- comboBox_3

Combobox 1 & 2 lists the vector layers available, however I would like the 3rd combobox to list the attribute column that both layers have in common (from the attribute table).

```
    # run method that performs all the real work
def run(self):
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    for layer in self.iface.legendInterface().layers():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(layer.name())
            self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(layer.name())
```

Comment: This project could be interesting for you: http://3nids.github.io/qgiscombomanager/

Comment: The info from the link will be useful to me later on. At the moment, I am focusing on connecting the combobox with the Attribute Fields but I do not know the correct terms to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this based on the [QGIS Combo Manager](http://3nids.github.io/qgiscombomanager/)

Just create your own filter for the fields in a subclass of FieldCombo. The following code is untested (literally), so please bear with me if there's a typo or other minor problems, and think of it as a reference.

```
from qgiscombomanager import *

class MyFieldCombo( FieldCombo ):
    def __init__(self, widget, vectorLayerCombo1, vectorLayerCombo2, initField="", options={}):
        FieldCombo.__init__(self, widget, vectorLayerCombo1, vectorLayerCombo2, initField, options)
        self.vectorLayerCombo1 = vectorLayerCombo1
        self.vectorLayerCombo2 = vectorLayerCombo2

    # Overrides the filter from FieldCombo. Will be called for every field
    # and should return True, if the field should be shown.
    def __isFieldValid(self, idx):
        if not FieldCombo.__isFieldValid(self, idx):
            return False

        for f in self.vectorLayerCombo2.pendingFields():
            # adjust this line to reflect your idea of "common"
            if f.name() == self.vectorLayerCombo1.pendingFields()[idx].name():
                return True
        return False

# run method that performs all the real work
def run(self):
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    self.vlc1 = VectorLayerCombo( self.dlg.comboBox )
    self.vlc2 = VectorLayerCombo( self.dlg.comboBox_2 )
    self.fc = MyFieldCombo( self.dlg.comboBox_3 )
```